# Redirect stdin in a script to another process

Tags: bash, pipe

Say I have a bash script that get some input via stdin. Now in that script I want to launch another process and have that process get the same data via its stdin.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo STDIN | somecommand
```

Now the "echo STDIN" thing above is obviously bogus, the question is how to do that? I could use read to read each line from stdin, append it into a temp file, then

```
cat my_temp_file | somecommand
```

but that is somehow kludgy.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have a script like e.g. `myscript.sh`, and, _inside_ that script, you have, say, a `cat` command, and you want to run `myscript.sh < myfile` so the contents of `myfile` are received as standard input by `cat`. Is it? Because in that case you don't have to do anything, the stdin of your script is redirected to its inner commands.

Comment: @javidcf: Ah, yes. How could I oversee something as simple as that? Write down your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you write a bash script, the standard input is automatically inherited by any command within it that tries to read it, so, for example, if you have a script `myscript.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "this is my cat"
cat
echo "I'm done catting"
```

And you type:

```
$ myscript.sh < myfile
```

You obtain:

```
this is my cat
<... contents of my file...>
I'm done catting
```

Answer (score 2):

Can `tee` help you?

```
echo 123 | (tee >( sed s/1/a/ ) >(sed s/3/c/) >/dev/null )
```