# Bash: check STDIN before sending to another program

Tags: linux, bash, stdin

If I have a simple bash script called `child.sh` as:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "About to cat"
cat
echo "I'm done catting"
```

I can call it successfully like so:

```
./child.sh < myfile.txt
```

However, if I have another bash script called `parent.sh` which checks STDIN and subsequently calls `child.sh` if a condition is met, the call to child.sh will fail. So `parent.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$(</dev/stdin)

cnt=$(echo "$INPUT" | wc -l)

if [ $cnt -eq 3 ]
then

        echo "Calling child"
        exec ./child.sh < "$INPUT"
        echo "Finished Parent"

fi
```

Calling the `parent.sh` script as `./parent.sh < myfile.txt` results in the following error message:

```
Calling child
./parent.sh: line 11: This is the contents of my file
2nd line of my file
3rd line of my file: No such file or directory
Finished Parent
```

Is it possible to capture STDIN, check if a condition is met and subsequently send the STDIN to another program if this condition is met??

This question ([Redirect stdin in a script to another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604966/redirect-stdin-in-a-script-to-another-process)) is somewhat similar but only deals with sending redirected STDIN to 1 bash script. This question ([Bash: examine stdin but forward it intact to another program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336861/bash-examine-stdin-but-forward-it-intact-to-another-program)) is also similar but deals with STDIN line by line whereas I do not need to process line by line and also, in reality, my STDIN is very large and difficult to process line by line.

Comment: `./child.sh <<< "$INPUT"` ?

Comment: This fixed the issue! If you put it as an answer I will gladly accept. Just reading about the difference between < and <<<. I see that <<< can be used instead of typing in the text but why do I use <<< instead of < in this case??

Comment: `<` is for files, `<<<` is for strings. `< file.txt` will feed the content of file.txt to the command while `<<< "$var"` will feed the expansion of var to the command

Comment: Be aware this may block at the assignment to `INPUT` if streaming from an ongoing pipe.